# Gradle Build does not resolve activities

Tags: android, annotations, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, build.gradle

i have a problem in gradle assembly.
I using gradle plugin v3.0.1 + Android Studio v3.0.1 + JRE v1.8.0_152.

It's not working with annotationProcessor.

Result after run command `gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace`:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

My top-level build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My App `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


def AAVersion = '4.4.0'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.corporate.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:3.0.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

don't resolve my activities (annotated) :

[image]

Am i missing something?

Comment: It's show many error like this: 
Error:(49, 32) error: cannot find symbol class LoginActivity_

Comment: Is there any compile time error in PaymentMenuActivity class? Please clear the things if you find any, then import the class.

Comment: I think that i found the error. The project was misconfigured.
Initially had a package name but later there was change.
I hit this and the apk build succeeded.
Thanks!